# Setup an Account Password Reset to expire in Office 365 Exchange?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

Is there a way to setup a user account so that it's password expires (in the next 5 minutes) for purposes of testing out a password expiration policy in Office 365?

I'd like to do this on a test user to prove to my boss that it works.  My guess would be that in order for this to happen I would need to change a date value on the test user so that there would be five minutes between the date value and now().

Comment: Where do these accounts originate? DirSync on-premise with password synchronization?

Comment: We manually enter them as needed.  Initially the the old exchange server was synced with Office 365.